# pro android augmentation chapter 8 example throwing a NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

I have compiled the example for android pro development chapter 8. I am receiving this error when I try and run one of the patterns on the phone.

I have checked this link to try and understand this error more clearly http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html
From my understanding this errors is created at run time and not compile time.

Here is the manifest which shows that the various activity has been successful added to the manifest

Its ok I fixed it. The problem was that there was an issues with the lib and libs folders. I removed the libs folder and removed the libraries from the lib folder and then when to the java build path and added these jar files for AdAR.jar. This fixed the issues.

```
07-29 21:00:06.378: E/AndroidRuntime(19501): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-29 21:00:06.378: E/AndroidRuntime(19501): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.paar.ch8.ModelViewer
07-29 21:00:06.378: E/AndroidRuntime(19501):    at com.paar.ch8.ModelChooser.onListItemClick(ModelChooser.java:91)
07-29 21:00:06.378: E/AndroidRuntime(19501):    at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
07-29 21:00:06.378: E/AndroidRuntime(19501):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
07-29 21:00:06.378: E/AndroidRuntime(19501):    at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3763)
07-29 21:00:06.378: E/AndroidRuntime(19501):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1936)
07-29 21:00:06.378: E/AndroidRuntime(19501):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-29 21:00:06.378: E/AndroidRuntime(19501):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-29 21:00:06.378: E/AndroidRuntime(19501):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-29 21:00:06.378: E/AndroidRuntime(19501):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
07-29 21:00:06.378: E/AndroidRuntime(19501):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-29 21:00:06.378: E/AndroidRuntime(19501):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-29 21:00:06.378: E/AndroidRuntime(19501):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
07-29 21:00:06.378: E/AndroidRuntime(19501):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
07-29 21:00:06.378: E/AndroidRuntime(19501):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Link to this tutorial? Or how should I know what you are talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. I removed the lib directory and then went to jave build path which now said the jar files are missing. I then went to add external jar and then added the files in. I then ran the project. This fixed the error.